# php link to call another php page

Tags: php

i have a php page which contain this field:

```
<a href src='delcat.php'>Delete</a>
```

i want when i press on the Delete to call the delcat.php and send a categoryid which is in a field in the same table.
any one can help me to reach this please?
here my complete table code:

```
<table border="0" align='center' class="styled-table">
            <tr class="thh">
    <th class="thh">Category Code</th>
            <th class="thh">Category Name </th>
            <th class="thh">Category IMage </th>
            <th class="thh">Edit</th>
    <th class="thh">Delete</th>
            </tr>
    <?php
    for ($counter = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_row ($resultSet); $counter++) {
      print ("<tr align='center' class='trh'>");
      print ("<td align='center' class='tdh'>$row[0]</td>");
      print ("<td align='center' class='tdh'>$row[1]</td>");
      print ("<td align='center' class='tdh'><img src='$row[2]' width='50' height='50'></td>");
      print ("<td align='center' class='tdh' width='50' align='center'><a href ='#'>Edit</a></td>"); 
      print ("<td align='center' class='tdh' width='50' align='center'><a href ='delcat.php'>Delete</a></td>");  
      print("</tr>");       
      }
```

Comment: What is `<a href src='delcat.php'>`?

Comment: `<?php echo '<a href="delcat.php?categoryid=' . $row[0] . '">delete</a>"; ?>`

Comment: "Delete i want when i press on the Delete to call the delcat.php and send a categoryid which is in a field in the same table" is ambiguous. Maybe you or someone can modify the sentence.

Comment: @VishalVerma It looked ambiguous because he didn't use proper markdown, so his HTML was inlined.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<a href src='delcat.php'>
```

To this:

```
<a href='delcat.php?categoryid=" . $row[0] . "'>
```

Comment: `src` attribute in an `A` tag?

Comment: @Barmar Didn't see that; copied the OP's code and added the var to the end. Fixed - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the category Id as querystring in href.

```
<a href='delcat.php?categoryId=".$row[0]."'>Delete</a>
```

And retrieve using `$_GET['categoryId']` on delcat.php page.

One more way is you can use [http_build_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-str.php).